# Is it possible to send files between 2 different MQTT brokers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt, mosquitto, emq

I am using 2 different MQTT Brokers(Mosquitto and EMQX). I am able to send messages between my mosquitto to EMQX and also EMQX to mosquitto using command prompt. I want to know if its possible to send files (png, pdf, xlsx, doc) between the two.

If yes, How?

Comment: You are asking multiple totally different questions here. Edit the question to ask just one and then ask a separate question for the other

Comment: Edited the question. @hardillb

Comment: A broker doesn't subscribe, you need two subscribers one to subscribe to each broker.

Comment: Yeah. All I had meant was if its possible to send files from using the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file would just be another message (MQTT messages are just byte arrarys, they can hold ANYTHING)

If you want to have messages be published to subscribing clients on both brokers then you need to set up a bridge between the 2 brokers.

How you setup a bridge with Mosquitto is documented in the mosquitto.conf man page [here](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html#idm633).

The same details for EMQ X can be found [here](http://emqtt.io/docs/v2/bridge.html)